# There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package

Tags: java, windows

I need help with this. It started with me trying to update Java & when I tried
this is the message I got:
"ERROR 1723: There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

I've already tried deleting Java 6 update 14, but it won't allow me to, oddly enough I get the same message. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be asked in superuser.com but I don't have enough **reputation** to move it.

Anyway, the installation package comes as a **msi** file, correct? If so you can try to run **[msiexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(WS.10).aspx)** with log enabled.

Best

Comment: Tryed such `msiexec /i jre-6u27-windows-x64.exe /Lime logfile.txt`, but it didn't help. Still receive error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the 1723 problem (Windows 7) when attempting to uninstall JRE 6.30. I don't think the version matters for this error.  I believe it is caused by having multiple version of Java installed at the same time.  When uninstalling one of them it removes some file needed to uninstall the other versions and you are left in a state where you can't reinstall or uninstall the JRE.  I used the [Microsoft FixIt tool](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)  [[stand alone download here]](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9775982).  I created the portable fixit and then ran on my local machine. The tool has a list of fixes and you need to find "Fix problems with programs that can't be installed or uninstalled" and click "Run Now".  The wizard is self-explanatory and after running will show something similar to this:

[image: microsoft fix it tool]

Once you see this, double check your control panel that the JRE was actually uninstalled (and attempt to install if desired).

Comment: This doesnt always delete the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\JavaSoft` folder which is responsible for this problem to begin with. I had to go manually delete it using regedit as in @Mockertin answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415485/remove-jre-entries-from-windows-registries/5953210#5953210) for additional information about solving this issue.

### Update:

Here is the brief summary of the original [Problems with Java installation discussion](http://forums.whatthetech.com/index.php?showtopic=104537).

Sometimes, when you attempt to run the java installer file you receive the message:

```
This software has already been installed on your computer. 
Would you like to reinstall it?
```

When you click Yes to the above question you receive the error:

```
This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.
```

This problem is caused because the Windows Installer information for a previous installation of Java has been removed or damaged, but the related registry keys are still present causing the Java installer to think it is already installed.

To fix this issue you should do the following:

1. If you are able, uninstall all previous versions of Java in add/remove programs in your control panel.
2. Next, you may download [the current version of Java](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
   It's recommended that you use the offline installer version.
3. Run the following commands in cmd:

_

```
reg query hklm\software\classes\installer\products /f "java(tm) 6" /s | find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" > deljava.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (deljava.txt) do reg delete %%a /f
del deljava.txt
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /f
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /f
```

Comment: Good answers have more details. Include and summarise the relevant information from the post you've linked to. It keeps all the information in one place and helps guard against link rot.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on my Windows 7 box where I was trying to uninstall Java and do a clean install of a newer version.  Something got messed up and I would get the 1723 error message during the uninstall and attempted reinstall.  Here's information about how I was able to fix the problem, and maybe this will help you:

Look at the log files for the uninstall/reinstall.  On Windows 7 they can be found at `c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\`

The `java_install.log`didn't show any extra information, but I had several `MSI#####` log files that contained error messages about the failed uninstall.  The message was: `Error 1723.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action UninstallJRE, entry: MSIUninstallJRE, library: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\regutils.dll`

There was indeed no `regutils.dll` file, and not even the `bin`directory was there. So I copied over a `regutils.dll` file from another computer, ran the uninstaller, and it worked.  Then the new clean install of Java also worked.

So take a look at your logfiles and hopefully that will give you more detailed information about the 1723 error.

Answer (score 0):

One way (only way which worked for me - i tried most of the things listed in this post, including MockerTims script) was to search through Windows Registry for Java and then carefully remove anything that seemed to point to the specific JRE version i wanted to remove.

Steps are roughly as such:

1. Hit Windows button and type into the search field "regedit". Pick the result of the search, which is regedit.exe.
2. Select the top of the tree and hit CTRL + F.
3. Type in Java to 'Find what' field and hit enter.
4. Manually go through every found object (hit F3 to proceed to the next item).
5. If the item is referring to the JRE version you want to remove, then delete the entry. Otherwise leave it be and continue on to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the tricks stated above and nothing was able to resolve my problem. Changing the path way, registry being corrupted, few dlls weren't able to be deleted and so on and on...  I used Fixit and deleted whatever I saw with the name JAVA. I tried installing GRE/JVM separately, nothing worked what so ever.

Solution..

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml

Use offline install of JAVA or some people call it silently install JAVA. This fixed my problem that I couldn't fix in two days. 
After this I was able to install eclipse without getting any pathway error message, or dll related messages.