# Different java version requested

Tags: java

From [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) repository

I try to run the following step

> Download Mairesse's tool PersonalityRecognizer and unzip it to the
>   same location. Check the installation instructions to properly
>   configure the tool.

However I receive this error:

```
$ ./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
./PersonalityRecognizer: line 15: ../../apps/jdk1.5.0_05/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

In this file, which is from the tool, I setted the version of java I have

```
@echo off
rem WINDOWS LAUNCH SCRIPT

rem ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES TO MODIFY

set JDK_PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151"
set WEKA="H:\apps\weka-3-4\weka.jar"

rem ----------------------------------

set COMMONS_CLI="lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar"
set JMRC="lib\jmrc.jar"

set LIBS=%WEKA%;%COMMONS_CLI%;%JMRC%;%CD%;bin\

%JDK_PATH%\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath %LIBS% recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Why the error shows a different version and path? What can I do?

if I type in cmd the followning I see a different path.

```
C:\Users\myuser>which java
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java
```

How can I change it which jdk if this is the option to fix the problem?

Comment: The error message look like the system OS is not windows based (like linux or mac), but the config file you are posted shows windows paths. On which OS are you working on? How/where do you start the `PersonalityRecognizer` application? What is the current content of the configuration file and where is it located?

Comment: @Program not sure if this is an error `C:\Users\myuser>which java
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java`

Comment: Have you “ Check the installation instructions to properly configure the tool.”?

Comment: @Program I work in windows 10. Due to the instructions of the link I opened the file named `PersonalityRecognizer.bat if you're using Windows` and made the changes. I just added the PersonalityRecognizer file into the file I have from the repository.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if you mean this instructions from repository `Open the file PersonalityRecognizer.properties (or PersonalityRecognizer.properties.win if you're using Windows) and edit the variable appDir with the full path to the folder PersonalityRecognizer
Open the file PersonalityRecognizer (or PersonalityRecognizer.bat if you're using Windows) and edit the variable JDK_PATH with the full path to the root of your Java installation.` Yes I made them

Comment: Java used (possibly still uses) registry keys to set this stuff too.  The best bet if it s available is to use the java control panel to fix it.  If the java control panel isn't available you can manually edit the registry:  on the command line you can run `regedit` and look under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft` -- there should be a couple of registry entries with old path values

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415485/how-to-remove-jre-entries-from-windows-registry